# Unable to create Dataframe

Tags: python, dataframe, apache-spark, hadoop, pyspark

I am trying to run a simple PySpark program to test.

Here is my code:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":    
spark = SparkSession.builder \    
    .appName("Welcome Spark") \    
    .master("local[2]") \    
    .getOrCreate()    

data_list = [("Aishwarya", 21),("Jhanavi", 19),("Maithree", 23),];

df = spark.createDataFrame(data_list).toDF("Name", "Age")    
df.show()
```

I am trying to add the list to a dataframe. I am getting an error while creating the data frame.

```
data_list = [("Aishwarya", 21),("Jhanavi", 19),("Maithree", 23),];  
df = spark.createDataFrame(data_list).toDF("Name", "Age") 
df.show()
```

Comment: Please share the error you get

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try below two methods, both works for me:

```
# option 1

data_list = [("Aishwarya", 21),("Jhanavi", 19),("Maithree", 23),]

new_dfdf = spark.createDataFrame(data_list).toDF("Name", "Age")
new_dfdf.show(3)

# option 2

op_dfdf = spark.createDataFrame(data_list, ("Name", "Age"))
op_dfdf.show(3)
```

Answer (score 0):

This works for me.

```
import pyspark
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

if __name__ == "__main__":
    spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("Welcome Spark").master("local[*]").getOrCreate()
    data_list = [("Aishwarya", 21),("Jhanavi", 19),("Maithree", 23),];
    df = spark.createDataFrame(data_list).toDF("Name", "Age")
    df.show()
```